# IDA Hex-Rays: How to find all references to the certain field of all instances of the data type?

Tags: ida, hexrays

[This question has already been asked here](https://reverseengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/20115/ida-hex-rays-there-are-no-xrefs-to) but for some reason it was deleted, as "dead".

I will try to explain again. I have a specific data type. It is used in a large number of disassembled functions. This type has a field whose purpose is unknown. I need to find all references to this field in the entire application.

I can belive to @Biswapriyo, that this behavior is by design and I cannot find xrefs to the field of data type. Ok, got it. Now I need to find a way to do that! :)

Perhaps there are any plugin? I don't understand why this can be difficult, since to perform this action, it is enough to generate a .c file, open it in notepad and press Ctrl+F. I want this functionality to be in IDA Hex-Rays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

IDA does support structure member cross-references: it will show you everywhere in the disassembly listing that an instruction operand has had that particular structure reference applied to it. See this picture: [image: IDA structure cross-references]

However, this only works if the structure has been applied on the assembly-language level. Generally speaking, changing the type of a variable in Hex-Rays does not result in structure cross-references being created. Personally, I think this should be standard behavior.

Nevertheless, there's a Hex-Rays plugin called [Referee](https://github.com/jkoppel/project-ironfist/tree/master/tools/Revitalize/Referee) that automatically adds assembly-level structure references based on the Hex-Rays types. There's also an [IDAPython port of Referee](https://github.com/joeleong/ida-referee). At the time of writing, neither the C++ nor the IDAPython version has been ported to the latest IDA 7.x SDK.

Answer (score 2):

(Since I can't add comments due reputation)
I ported IDAPython version of Referee to IDA 7.x (works on 7.5 good so far)
Repository is [here](https://github.com/gamelaster/ida-referee)